# Methods in Google Earth Engine to correct the impact of sunlight on water bodies

Tags: google-earth-engine

There are very high reflectivity water bodies on both Landsat and Sentinel satellites, which is very troublesome when retrieving water quality parameters. Are there any simple and effective methods to remove or correct them?